# Is there a data structure that allows you to return all the sets that contain this element?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set

I am looking for a data structure that returns all sets that contain a given element, as well as supporting set addition and deletion operations

The obvious approach is to store each set as a hash table and for each query check whether the sets contain a given element

But there are some limitations

1. The given sets can intersect each other or even contain
2. It is guaranteed that the number of elements is much larger than the number of sets
3. It is necessary to support the operation of updating and deleting sets

More stricly

Given a number of sets **S_1, S_2, S_3, ... S_n**. Each set is defined by an enumeration of its elements 
I need a data structure that will allow me to effectively perform the following operations: 
`get(E)` - *Get all sets that contain a given element E* 
`add(i, S)` - *Add the i-th set* 
`update(i, S)` - *Update the i-th set* 
`delete(i)` - *Delete the i-th set*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure you are looking for is a [(sparse) bipartite (undirected) graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).

[image: example of bipartite graph]
*([CC BY-SA 4.0 Watchduck](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Simple_bipartite_graph;_two_layers.svg))*

Here, for each element `e` and each set `S` you would have an extra vertex. And for each `e in S` you would have an edge `{e,S} in E`. Then, examining set `S` boils down to: give me `S`'s neighbours. Examining all sets `e` belongs to boils down to: give me `e`'s neighbours. Adding values to sets means inserting new edges, and removing elements means removing edges. You might also want to make sure to entirely remove isolated vertices.